# Iterate through object and set value for empty fields

Tags: java

I have a VO similar to this.

```
public class Job
{
    private Long id;
    private String createdBy;
    private Set<JobStatus> jobStatuses;
}
```

And many more similar fields. I want to iterate through the fields in VO and set 'NA' for all String fields which doesn't have data. This is what I have so far.

```
Job job = getJob();//getting the Job populated
BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Job.class);
for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDesc : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
    if (propertyDesc.getReadMethod().invoke(job) == null
        && propertyDesc.getPropertyType() == String.class) {
      propertyDesc.getWriteMethod().invoke(job, "NA");
}}
```

This works well. But now I need to iterate through the other fields which are objects by itself and do the same dynamically. Like `Set<JobStatus> jobStatuses`. How can I do it ?

Comment: You didn't want to use reflection... but how do you think your current code works under the covers...?  As for your question, what's stopping you from defining a default value for other object types and setting it the same way? Side note - why are you doing this instead of leaving them blank/empty? Things like "NA" should ideally be display-time specifics, not actually stored in the model like this.

Comment: Got your point. I can't set a default value since the VO is actually a hibernate entity, and I don't want 'NA' to be persisted in DB. Will look into handling this in UI.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this is just bad practice.
If you want to save your object in the database and want the empty attributes to be saved as 'NA' (for whatever reason) just set the default value for the column to 'NA'.
You can also initialize the object with attribute values = 'NA' in the constructor saves you much time that looping through the object properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize those variables in the constructor with N/A, you could also have a method on each object that sets the null variables to N/A and just call it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign string values to the Java objects that are not `String` types. But I am assuming it is ok for you assign an empty object constructed from a default constructor, if exists, to properties that are null. With that assumption, try the following solution:

```
for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDesc : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
    if (propertyDesc.getReadMethod().invoke(job) == null
        && propertyDesc.getPropertyType() == String.class) {
               propertyDesc.getWriteMethod().invoke(job, "NA");
    }
    else if (propertyDesc.getReadMethod().invoke(job) == null
        && propertyDesc.getPropertyType() != String.class) { //Other than String types                   
               propertyDesc.getWriteMethod().invoke(job, propertyDesc.getPropertyType().newInstance());
    }   
}
```

Don't forget to handle this code with a try-catch block. Not all objects in your class might have a default constructor in which case you might want to further customize your code.